# Symfony 4 - How to fix '404 Not Found' for a web api REST where routes does exists?

Tags: symfony, wamp, virtualhost, symfony4

I'm trying to implement a REST API with symfony 4. My problem is that I can't reach my routes for my method GET and POST. Everytime I try, I get a 404 error.

But when I try to get my routes on symfony, I have :

```
Name                            Method   Scheme   Host   Path

app_statistics_poststatistics   POST     ANY      ANY    /api/stat
app_statistics_getstatistics    GET      ANY      ANY    /api/stat/{statId}
```

So my routes does exist, but I can't reach them.

I'm working on a Windows Environment with WAMP to work in local.

I've already tried my api on 2 windows environnment and on one Linux environnment with LAMP. Always getting a 404 Not Found.

The author of the tutorial told me that my api was working on his computer, but I don't have more info about his environnment. So, I expect the problem to come from the configuration of my virtual host.

Here is my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName statroche.fr
    ServerAlias www.statroche.fr
    DocumentRoot "D:/other/symfony/testRoche/public"
    <Directory "D:/other/symfony/testRoche/public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Important note: I don't have anything in my public folder as I don't want any page, just the API, do I still need to put 'public' in `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` ?.

I would like to reach my API and then for the GET method for example, return a json. Actually, I can reach the `/` of my project but can't reach other routes.

Comment: So, if you don't have `index.php` in the `public` folder, you have no entrypoint for Symfony to start running - do you see the usual welcome page when accessing `/`?

Comment: No, I can't see the classic welcome page, but I can reach the `/` with the `+Indexes` in my Virtual host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't want to build an "old-style website" with Symfony, you have to use `index.php` to bootstrap Symfony and to make the API accessible

Comment: I created a new project to try with an index.php in my public folder. Now there is an error that I can't understand. Here is the error 
`NotAcceptableHttpException - 

No matching accepted Response format could be determined`
which refer to my file fos_rest.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<Directory "D:/other/symfony/testRoche/public">
```

Point apache directory Path to the main folder of your Symfony project like this

```
<Directory "D:/other/symfony/testRoche">
```

Then, use **.htaccess** file (place it in `D:/other/symfony/testRoche/.htaccess` to make **public/index.php** as the main endpoint if you go to http://localhost:80

The full apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName statroche.fr
    ServerAlias www.statroche.fr
    DocumentRoot "D:/other/symfony/testRoche/public"
    <Directory "D:/other/symfony/testRoche/public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ public/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```